# Explenation needed: Weird MySQL2 Behavior: Query Result omits 1 row, unless

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

When querying a SELECT to the MySQLDB 1 line was strangely omitted from the results. After brute forcing for the error I found out, that the full result is only returned when the query is executed in the callback of another SELECT query function.:

Full result:

```
getQueueTime(() => {
  getOrders();
})
```

1 Line Omitted:
`getOrders();`

Now I dont understand at all why this would happen, since only SELECT Queries are used and I´d be grateful for a short explanation. A simplified version of the functions below:

```
function getQueueTime(callback) {
    const sql = "SELECT SUM(queue_time) AS total_queue_time FROM Orders WHERE order_status = 'Processing'"

    pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
            connection.query(sql, (error, results) => {
               connection.release();

                    let queue_time = results[0].total_queue_time;

                    callback(queue_time);
            }); 
    });
}
```

```
function getOrders(status) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const sql = "SELECT * FROM Orders AS o JOIN OrderItems AS oi ON o.order_id = oi.order_id JOIN Food AS f on oi.food_id = f.food_id WHERE o.order_status = 'Processing'";
    
    connection.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        connection.query(sql, (error, results) => {
            console.log(results);
            connection.release();
            resolve(results);  //Here The results I´m talking about

    //rest of logic
   })
  })
 })
}
```

I tried simply using another query in the same function to maybe replicate it and also tried using only an empty callback function, both to no prevail.

Comment: Maybe something to do with record locking. I may be wrong as I don't exactly know how record locking works but in any case, it makes sense to wait for one query to return before starting another query on the same table.

Comment: You're not passing an argument for the `status` parameter when you call `getOrders()`.

Comment: Your code is very unclear. `getOrders()` returns a promise, but you never use `await` or `.then()` to process the results.